# MAC OSx Codesigning fastlane jenkins

Tags: macos, jenkins, fastlane, codesign

I've have an issue when running fastlane within jenkins.

The code-signing of the frameworks is failing in the Pods-XXXX-frameworks.sh script, only when running under jenkins.

in the PODS-script:

rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" "/Users/lucjusgen/Desktop/Jenkins/workdir/workspace/vindeenjob-ios/vindeenjob-ios-build/derivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/VindEenJobAppRelease/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Alamofire.framework" "/Users/lucjusgen/Desktop/Jenkins/workdir/workspace/vindeenjob-ios/vindeenjob-ios-build/derivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/VindEenJobAppRelease/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications//VDABVindEenJob.app/Frameworks"
/usr/bin/codesign --force --verbose --sign 4FD1765CE3BF91BDAEF471622F47BD8E7AE35B1D  --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements '/Users/lucjusgen/Desktop/Jenkins/workdir/workspace/vindeenjob-ios/vindeenjob-ios-build/derivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/VindEenJobAppRelease/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications//VDABVindEenJob.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework'

/Users/lucjusgen/Desktop/Jenkins/workdir/workspace/vindeenjob-ios/vindeenjob-ios-build/derivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/VindEenJobAppRelease/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications//VDABVindEenJob.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework: **errSecInternalComponent**

When running the commands manually:

rsync --delete -av --filter "P .*.??????" --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" "/Users/lucjusgen/Desktop/Jenkins/workdir/workspace/vindeenjob-ios/vindeenjob-ios-build/derivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/VindEenJobAppRelease/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Alamofire.framework" "/Users/lucjusgen/Desktop/Jenkins/workdir/workspace/vindeenjob-ios/vindeenjob-ios-build/derivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/VindEenJobAppRelease/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications//VDABVindEenJob.app/Frameworks"

/usr/bin/codesign --force --verbose --sign 4FD1765CE3BF91BDAEF471622F47BD8E7AE35B1D  --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements '/Users/lucjusgen/Desktop/Jenkins/workdir/workspace/vindeenjob-ios/vindeenjob-ios-build/derivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/VindEenJobAppRelease/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications//VDABVindEenJob.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework'

**/Users/lucjusgen/Desktop/Jenkins/workdir/workspace/vindeenjob-ios/vindeenjob-ios-build/derivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/VindEenJobAppRelease/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications//VDABVindEenJob.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework: signed bundle with Mach-O universal (armv7 arm64) [org.cocoapods.Alamofire]**

Any idea why this is different under Jenkins?
Do I miss some environment settings? 
The rest of the fastlane gym is running fine.